# DocumentDb JOIN not returning result if JOINED property doesn't exist

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

My typical document for a user looks like this:

```
{
   "id": "SomeGuid",
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName": "Smith",
   "pet": { "id": "anotherGuid", "name": "Fluffy" }
}
```

If the user doesn't have a pet, I don't even save the pet property in DocumentDb so the user document would look like this:

```
{
   "id": "Guid123",
   "firstName": "Jane",
   "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

I want to get a list of my users along with their pet names so here's my SQL:

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstName, c.lastName, p.name
FROM c
JOIN p IN c.pet
```

This SELECT is not returning any data. If I remove the JOIN and get only user information, it works fine.

How do I get all users? If they have a pet, I should get the pet's name, if not, no pet name. Using my example, I want to get a list that looks like this:

```
[
   { "id": "SomeGuid", "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "name": "Fluffy" },
   { "id": "Guid123", "firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe" }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I want by NOT using a JOIN.

Here's my SELECT that gives me exactly what I want:

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.pet.name
FROM c
```

The result I get is exactly what I want which is:

```
[
   { "id": "SomeGuid", "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "name": "Fluffy" },
   { "id": "Guid123", "firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe" }
]
```